# Center aligning images and text within a table for a responsive contact page

Tags: css, alignment, center, css-tables, responsiveness

I've been fiddling around with this page for some time now, but I can't seem to figure out how to center align the images and text relative to the table.

http://www.thomasoosting.nl/contact/

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the `display: inline-block` from the class `.contactTabel`.